# Let y be a group element of order m; if $m=dt$ for some $d\geq 1$, prove that $y^t$ has order d

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let y be a group element of order m; if $m=dt$ for some $d\geq 1$, prove that $y^t$ has order d.

Suppose $\exists x \in \mathbb{z}$, where $x<d$, such that $(y^t)^x$=1. Then, 
$$(y^t)^x = y^{xt} = 1.$$
$x<d$ implies that $xt<dt=m$ for all $t>0$. Since y is a group element of order m, 
$$y^m = y^{dt} = 1 = y^{xt},$$ implies that $$xt=m=dt,$$ and furthermore that $x=d$. This is a contradiction since $x<d$, thus there exists no such x. Therefore, $y^t$ has order d. Q.E.D.

Is my argument correct? Also, would this be considered a "senior-level" proof?

Want to note that this is from Rotman-"A First Course in Abstract Algebra", question 2.40

Comment: Yes, but it's rather a proof by contraposition. I don't know what is called a ‘senior-level’ proof.

Comment: Neither do I (lol). My professor tells me that a lot. I take it to mean that my proof needs to better stated.

Comment: I would prove that, if $x<d$, then $(y^t)^x\neq 1$ because of the very definition of the order of $y$.

Comment: Ok, with that it follows directly that $(y^t)^x < (y^t)^d = y^m = 1$. So simple.

Comment: `<`? What does that mean, in an abstract group? I suppose it is: since $tx<m$, then ….

Comment: Since $tx<m$, no matter the x, $y^{tx}$ never is the identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make the implication $y^m = y^{xt} \implies xt = m$. If $k$ is a positive integer such that $y^k = 1$, you can only conclude $m | k$ as $m$ is the order of $y$.

Let $n$ be the order of $y^t$. Since $y$ has order $m$, $(y^t)^d = y^{dt} = y^m = 1$. Therefore, $n | d$. On the other hand, by the Euclidean algorithm, $n = qd + r$ for some integers $q$ and $r$ with $0 \le r < d$. Since

$$y^{tr} = y^{tn - qdt} = (y^t)^n (y^m)^{-q} = 1$$

and $0 \le tr < m$, we must have $tr = 0$ (since $m$ is the smallest positive integer for which $y^m = 1$). Hence $r = 0$ and $n = qd$. So $d | n$, and consequently $n = d$.

Comment: If $r=0$ and $n=qd+r$ how do you conclude that $d=nq$?

Comment: @SOULed_Outt that was a typo. I just fixed it. It's $n = qd$.

Comment: I see. In my attempt I was trying to show that there's no x<d such that $(y^t)^x = 1$. Your method is very interesting because I'd never think to use the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @kobe, how do you know $n|d$ ?

Comment: Hi @grayQuant, since $y^t$ has order $n$ and $(y^t)^d = 1$, $n$ divides $d$.